# Divs sticking out of parent div

Tags: css, html

I am designing a shopping cart site, where I have several parent divs as well as child divs as follows. The Issue is the divs where I have set to height:auto is not expanding when the child content is growing, No in my case i needed to add another set of (3) item-holders(already it has 3 and fits with the content) inside items div but when I do it jumps out of the parent div. Please help me on this.

My HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>diluks eCommerce - Home</title>
<link href="scripts/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="level1">
    <div class="profile-bar"></div>

  </div>
  <div class="level2">
    <div class="logoarea"><img src="img/logo-bar.png" width="1000" height="100" /></div>

  </div>
  <div class="level3">
    <div class="body-content">
      <div class="side-bar"></div>
      <div class="nav-menu"></div>
      <div class="image-slider"><img src="img/main-img.png" width="785" height="220" /></div>
      <div class="seperate-space">
        <div class="separate-title"><a class="bold-captions">Latest Picks</a></div>


      </div>
<div class="items">
  <div class="item-holder">
        <table align="center" width="256px" cellpadding="0px" cellspacing="0px">
            <tr>
                <td class="item-info" align="center" height="34px">Item name</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="item-info" align="center" height="230px"><img src="img/sunflowers.png" width="256" height="230" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="item-info" align="center" height="34px">$30</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="item-info" align="center" height="35px">Button</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
  </div>
  <div class="item-holder">
        <table align="center" width="256px" cellpadding="0px" cellspacing="0px">
            <tr>
                <td class="item-info" align="center" height="34px">Item name</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="item-info" align="center" height="230px"><img src="img/treecard.png" width="256" height="230" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="item-info" align="center" height="34px">$30</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="item-info" align="center" height="35px">Button</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
  </div>
  <div class="item-holder">
        <table align="center" width="256px" cellpadding="0px" cellspacing="0px">
            <tr>
                <td class="item-info" align="center" height="34px">Item name</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="item-info" align="center" height="230px"><img src="img/3-flowers.png" width="256" height="230" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="item-info" align="center" height="34px">$30</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="item-info" align="center" height="35px">Button</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
  </div>


</div>
    </div>


  </div>
  <div class="level4">
    <div class="footer-area">
      <div class="space-line"></div>
    </div>


  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

My CSS Style Sheet

```
@charset "utf-8";
.container {
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
body{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    background-color:#F2F2F2;

    }.container .level1 {
    height: 35px;
    width: 100%;

}
.container .level2 {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;

}
.container .level3 {
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    min-height:685px;
}
.level3 .body-content {
    height: 100%;
    width: 1000px;
    min-height:685px;
    margin:auto;
}
.body-content .side-bar {
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 200px;
    min-height:685px;
    background-color:#CACACA;

}
.body-content .nav-menu {
    float: left;
    height: 35px;
    width: 800px;

    background-color:#CACACA;
}
.body-content .items {
    float: left;
    height: auto;
    width: 785px;
    min-height:335px;
    padding-left:15px;
    padding-bottom:15px;
    padding-top:15px;
    padding-right:0px;
    position:relative;


}
.logoarea {
    height: 100px;
    width: 1000px;
    margin:auto;
    border-bottom-style:solid;
    border-bottom-width:1px;
    border-bottom-color:#CACACA;
}
.profile-bar {
    height: 35px;
    width: 1000px;
    margin:auto;
    border-bottom-style:solid;
    border-bottom-width:1px;
    border-bottom-color:#666;
}
.image-slider {
    float: left;
    height: 220px;
    width: 785px;
    padding-left:15px;
    padding-bottom:15px;
    padding-top:15px;
    padding-right:0px;

}
.level4 {
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    min-height:150px;
}
.space-bar{
    height: 15px;
    width: 100%;
    }
.space-line{
    height: 15px;
    width: 100%;
    border-top-style:solid;
    border-top-width:1px;
    border-top-color:#666;
    }   .footer-area {
    height: auto;
    width: 1000px;
    margin:auto;
    min-height:150px;
}
.seperate-space {
    float: left;
    height: 35px;
    width: 785px;
    padding-left:15px;
}
.separate-title {
    float: left;
    height: 28px;
    width: 780px;
    background-color:#CACACA;

    padding-top:7px;
    padding-left:5px;

}
.items .item-holder {
    float: left;
    height: 335px;
    width: 260px;
}
.item-info{
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    color:#333;
    }
.bold-captions{
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#333;
    }
```

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mrvijayakumar/mUwv3/)

Comment: can you put your code in jsfiddle? So that we can assist you better.

Comment: Try using `overflow: hidden`.

Comment: The overflow: auto answer below works, but take a few minutes to read this post and familiarize yourself with floats and clearing them. http://www.impressivewebs.com/clearing-floats-why-necessary/

Comment: @Bhushan JSFiddle Demo is there..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/bortao/XpSXK/

First had to use `clearfix` on `level3` so the floated content is contained there (your main question).

Then there was a problem with the side bar: it always ended on it's min-height. so setting it to `height:100%` have no effect. Also, if there is content after this min-height, it would be aligned left below the side bar.

So i brought `side-bar` outside of `body-content` to make all content aligned to the right of the side bar.

And finally to make the rest of the side bar the same color, set the background color of `level3` to dark (same as side bar), and `body-content` background light, same as body.

Answer (score 4):

Add `overflow: auto`

```
.container .level3 {
   height: auto;
   width: 100%;
   min-height: 685px;
   overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: I would recommend the OP to read this post to get a solid handle on what it means to clear floats: http://www.impressivewebs.com/clearing-floats-why-necessary/

Comment: sidebar still on min-height

Comment: @Mahesh Sapkal It adds a horizontal scrollbar, not what i need

Comment: @MaheshSapkal Still it breaks the container as well as body-content, in JSFiddle can't see the borders of divs, so it seems fine in js fiddle, but in dreamweaver you can see the collapsing

Answer (score -1):

Add float:left to all your level divs

```
.level1,.level2,.level3,.level4{
        float:left;
    }
```

Comment: It pushes down the footer correctly and adds item-holders as I expected, but the body-content stays with the same height, where then items div jumps out of body-content which is the parent of them, any suggestions?

Comment: include jquery library and add the following javascript code 
 
 `<script>
  $( document ).ready(function() {  
   $(".side-bar").height($(".level3").height());
  });
  
 </script>`